# How to get printers list and print the document to selected printers using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to get printers list and print the document to selected printers using JS for my web based POS Application. i was used Firefox **JS Print Setup addon** but it is no longer available now and they removed it.Please help me to sort this issue, i'm new to js.